# Reg UPS API address validation

Tags: php, api, ups

Error while doing address validation using UPS API

I am passing the below address parameters

```
$addrkeyfrmt[AddressLine][0]= '2920 Zoo Drive';
$addrkeyfrmt[AddressLine][1]= '';
$addrkeyfrmt[AddressLine][2]= '';

$addrkeyfrmt['PoliticalDivision2'] = 'San Diego';
$addrkeyfrmt['PoliticalDivision1'] = 'CA';
$addrkeyfrmt['PostcodePrimaryLow'] = '92112';

$addrkeyfrmt['CountryCode'] = 'US';
$request['AddressKeyFormat'] = $addrkeyfrmt;
```

The error I am getting is

```
{
   "code":2,
   "msg":"There's a problem with the address provided. We've provided suggestions below. Please choose which version of the address you would like to use.",
   "classification":[
      {
         "AddressLine":[
            "2920 ZOO DR"
         ],
         "PoliticalDivision2":"SAN DIEGO",
         "PoliticalDivision1":"CA",
         "PostcodePrimaryLow":"92101",
         "PostcodeExtendedLow":"1646",
         "Region":"SAN DIEGO CA 92101-1646",
         "CountryCode":"US"
      }
   ]
}
```

Could you please suggest. Thanks

Comment: That's not an error, you are trying to validate an address and the json response clearly say there is a problem with the address (wrong `PostcodePrimaryLow`), it also suggests you the right one. Not really sure what you want to help with.

Comment: Actually as per the provided classification, I changed and tried, But still not able to validate the address. I would like to validate the address. Thanks